# facebook sdk with eclipse issues

Tags: android, facebook, sdk

i'm trying to develop a basic application in eclipce (android) with facebook SDK and I get this error msg ! when I go over the word (in red) with mouse over it says : "@Deprecated
Constructor for Facebook object."

anyone know what I am doing wrong?
Thank you guys

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook object is deprecated in new Facebook SDK.
Please use Facebook SDK 3.0 or above, all the Facebook SDKs below 3.0 are depreciated.
Here is a nice tutorial for Facebook 3.0 SDK integration : http://www.kpbird.com/2013/03/android-login-using-facebook-sdk-30.html